# How to check if user call my app from another app on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I have two applications. For example the "A" application call my "B" application, do some stuff and return to my "A" application. That's okay, I handle this action with below method

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
```

But I would like to handle the tope left back button event too. So I use the `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` method for this. But if I would like to return from "B" application with my button (not with the top left back button) the `applicationWillEnterForeground` method always called, and I don't know which event happened.

How should I have to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `applicationWillEnterForeground`, using `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

When using your own button to move back, do so using a custom URL.

In `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation`, check if you came back from your other app.  If so, set a flag which you can check in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.